# UIImageOrientation to CIDetectorImageOrientation

Tags: ios, orientation, face-detection

Using `CIDetector` to detect faces in images, you need to specify image orientation which happens to be specified in TIFF and EXIF specifications according to the docs, which means it's different from `UIImageOrientation`. Google found the below function for me, I tried it but found that it seems incorrect, or I possibly missed something else, because sometimes the orientation is off. Anyone know what's going on? It seems that as soon as a photo is exported from an iDevice, then imported to another iDevice, the orientation information is lost/changes, thus causing some orientation mismatch.

```
- (int) metadataOrientationForUIImageOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
{
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp: // the picture was taken with the home button is placed right
            return 1;
        case UIImageOrientationRight: // bottom (portrait)
            return 6;
        case UIImageOrientationDown: // left
            return 3;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft: // top
            return 8;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cover them all, and do so without magic number assignments (The raw values for CGImagePropertyOrientation *could* change in the future though it's unlikely... still a good practice) you should Include the ImageIO framework and use the actual constants:

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
- (CGImagePropertyOrientation)CGImagePropertyOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
{
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUp;
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUpMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDown;
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDownMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeftMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight;
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRightMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeft;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4

```
func inferOrientation(image: UIImage) -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
  switch image.imageOrientation {
  case .up:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.up
  case .upMirrored:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.upMirrored
  case .down:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.down
  case .downMirrored:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.downMirrored
  case .left:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.left
  case .leftMirrored:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.leftMirrored
  case .right:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.right
  case .rightMirrored:
    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.rightMirrored
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
func convertImageOrientation(orientation: UIImageOrientation) -> CGImagePropertyOrientation  {
    let cgiOrientations : [ CGImagePropertyOrientation ] = [
        .up, .down, .left, .right, .upMirrored, .downMirrored, .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored
    ]

    return cgiOrientations[orientation.rawValue]
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the raw values for both are the same; unless this is documented somewhere and guaranteed to be so in the future, I wouldn't rely on this approach.